# Modeling a 1 to 1..n relationship in the database

Tags: database, postgresql

How would you model booked hotel room to guests relationship (in PostgreSQL, if it matters)? A room can have several guests, but at least one.

Sure, one can relate guests to bookings with a foreign key `booking_id`. But how do you enforce on the DBMS level that a room must have at least one guest?

May be it's just impossible?

Comment: You must have a very efficient hotel if it never has empty rooms.

Comment: Your design...  There's something wrong with it.

Comment: No, it's not impossible and there's nothing wrong with the design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, if you read the question, it states booked hotel rooms.  This is quite easy to do as follows:

```
Rooms:
    room_id primary key not null
    blah
    blah

Guests:
    guest_id primary key not null
    yada
    yada

BookedRooms:
    room_id primary key foreign key (Rooms:room_id)
    primary_guest_id foreign key (Guests:guest_id)

OtherGuestsInRooms:
    room_id foreign key (BookedRooms:room_id)
    guest_id foreign key (Guests:guest_id)
```

That way, you can enforce a booked room having at least one guest while the OtherGuests is a 0-or-more relationship.  You can't create a booked room without a guest and you can't add other guests without the booked room.

It's the same sort of logic you follow if you want an n-to-n relationship, which should be normalized to a separate table containing a 1-to-n and an n-to-1 with the two tables.

Answer (score 4):

In this context I suggest that the entity you are modeling is in fact a **BOOKING** - a single entity - rather than two entities of room and guest.

So the table would be something like

```
BOOKING
-------
booking id
room id
guest id (FK to table of guests for booking)
first date of occupancy
last date of occupancy
```

Where guest id is not nullable,
and you have another table to hold guests per booking...

```
GUESTS
------
guest id
customer id (FK to customer table)
```

Comment: This is a much better way of looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

You could designate one of the guests as the "primary" guest and have it map to a column on the Rooms table.  Of course, this is a ridiculous rule for a hotel, where it's perfectly valid to have a room with 0 guests (I very well could pay for a room and not stay there)...

Comment: He's talking about booked rooms - this is distinct from rooms.

Comment: True, but hotels don't actually document who's IN the rooms, they document who's paying for the rooms.  And hotels also have a primary contact for their bookings so they know who to contact when the check bounces...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is that a room BOOKING is for at least one guest.  ANSI standard SQL would allow you to express the constraint as an ASSERTION something like:

```
create assertion x as check
   (not exists (select * from booking b
                where not exists
                   (select * from booking_guest bg
                    where bg.booking_id = b.booking_id)));
```

However, I don't suppose Postgres supports that (I'm not sure any current DBMS does).

There is a way using materialized views and check constraints, but I've never seen this done in practice:

1) Create a materialised view as

```
select booking_id from booking b
where not exists 
   (select * from booking_guest bg 
    where bg.booking_id = b.booking_id);
```

2) Add a check constraint to the materialized view:

```
check (boooking_id is null)
```

This constraint will fail if ever the materialized view is not empty, i.e. if there is a booking with no associated guest.  However, you would need to be careful about the performance of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

What about a room which has not been rented out?  What you're looking for are reservations and a reservation presumably needs at least one guest on it.

I think what you're asking is whether you can guarantee that a reservation record is not added unless you have at least one guest for and you can't add a guest without a reservation.  It's a bit of a Catch-22 for most DBMSs systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should create a `bookings` table with three primary keys. But instead of referring to bookings rooms, you can refer to a `beds` table.

```
bookings:
  bed_id: foreign_key primary
  guest_id: foreign_key primary
  day: date primary
  bill_id: foreign_key not null

beds:
  room_id: foreign_key primary
```

Since being the `primary` implies being required, and since this is the only way a guest and a room can be related, it makes sure that there cannot be a booking without a guest.

Notice that there is only one `day` field. This requires that you create a booking for every day a guest will stay in a room, but also ensures that nothing will be accidentally booked twice. A bed can be booked by only one customer on any given day(which is not true for rooms)

The `bill_id` is there so that you can refer a booking to a specific record for a bill, which can also be referenced by other things such as minibar expenses.